# Python, splitting data in between multiple double quotation marks?

Tags: python, parsing

Is it possible to split the data in a list that looks similar to this:

```
random_data = 
    [my_data]
    Colour = "yellow"
    Day = "monday"
    Weight = "500kg"
    month = "May"
```

Where the contents of the colour, day etc. can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use python dictionary.

```
random_data = {"Colour": "yellow", "Day": "monday", "Weight": "500kg", "month": "May"}
```

you can change data by following

```
random_data["Colour"] = "red"
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not able to convert the data into a list format, there can be several hundred items.